# Sort by date on Excel, but I have dates with different format

Tags: excel, date, sorting, xlsx

So I wanted to sort [my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O0Ze.png) by dates, in which the order is DD/MM/YYYY, I found the sort from A to Z function in Home -> Sort&Filter

However it sorts my data from smallest DD to largest DD, then smallest MM to largest MM and so on, instead of actually sorting it by oldest to newest.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZjlu.png)

What can I do to make it really sort by oldest date to newest date?

I have like 800+ data which I cannot change the date order of them one by one...

Tried to use Custom list but not sure how it works...

Please please please help me... It would be really much appreciated.

Comment: It seems dates are not stored as date in excel (Check cells format). First you have to convert these dates to true date then you can sort from oldest to newest.

Comment: If they are stored as text then use `DATEVALUE()` function to convert as true date.

Comment: @Harun24HR all dates are stored as a serial number, assuming all said dates are entered correctly.

Comment: I changed them to British date, the excel is recognizing them as dates, but i just cannot sort them by oldest to newest...

Comment: Just built an exam question with dates as 22.4.20 and they sort fine.

Comment: As already commented you have probably have strings not the Excel Date type (cells seem to be left-justified which suggests strings, as Excel right-justifies dates/numbers by default). Another way to check is to select a cell then use the Ctrl-# key combination: this should remove any formatting and show you the ‘raw’ stored data. If strings use the VALUE function to convert from text to Date (using the Regional date setting on your system). The strings are in UK/European format, which could be causing an issue if your system is using US date formats.

Comment: If the dates are all text, as they appear to be, convert to "real" dates by using the `Data / Text To Columns` method.  At step 3, define the date type as `DMY` (assuming that's what they are in the data). Then you won't have issues related to any differences between the date data and your computer windows regional settings.